# how do I select directories and files in KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to select a file (picture), through a simple app I made using `file manager`, but I keep getting this error message: `kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <kivymd.uix.filemanager.filemanager.MDFileManager object at 0x000001D98DC5F890>, it already has a parent <kivy.uix.modalview.ModalView object at 0x000001D98DC5F4A0>`, whenever I click on the button to access files (i.e to open directories). I don't know want is wrong, I don't even know what I am doing wrong.

I would appreciate any help thanks.

Here's my .py file

```
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView

from kivymd.uix.filemanager import MDFileManager
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.toast import toast


from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window


Window.size = (300, 530)


class MainApp(MDApp):
    title = "File Manage"

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.events)
        self.manager_open = False
        self.manager = None

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Gray'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = '200'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'

        return Factory.ExampleFileManager()

    def file_manager_open(self):
        if not self.manager:
            self.manager = ModalView(size_hint=(1, 1), auto_dismiss=False)
            self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
                exit_manager=self.exit_manager, select_path=self.select_path)
            self.manager.add_widget(self.file_manager)
            self.file_manager.show('/')  # output manager to the screen
        self.manager_open = True
        self.manager.open()

    def select_path(self, path):
        '''It will be called when you click on the file name
        or the catalog selection button.

        :type path: str;
        :param path: path to the selected directory or file;
        '''

        self.exit_manager()
        toast(path)

    def exit_manager(self, *args):
        '''Called when the user reaches the root of the directory tree.'''

        self.manager.dismiss()
        self.manager_open = False

    def events(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        '''Called when buttons are pressed on the mobile device..'''

        if keyboard in (1001, 27):
            if self.manager_open:
                self.file_manager.back()
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

and here's my .kv file:

```
<ExampleFileManager@BoxLayout>
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        id: progress_toolbar
        title: 'Progress'

    ScrollView:
        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 2
            adaptive_height: True
            spacing: (10, 15)
            padding: [25, 25]

            MDLabel:
                halign: 'center'
                text: 'Before'

            MDLabel:
                halign: 'center'
                text: 'Now'

            MDCard:
                ripple_behavior: True
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                size: 120, 220
                elevation: 15
                radius: 8
                MDIconButton:
                    icon: "camera-outline"
                    user_font_size: "64sp"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    on_release: app.file_manager_open()

            MDCard:
                ripple_behavior: True
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                size: 120, 220
                elevation: 15
                radius: 8
                MDIconButton:
                    icon: "camera-outline"
                    user_font_size: "64sp"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    on_release: app.file_manager_open()


            MDTextField:
                hint_text: 'Date'
                width: 100

            MDTextField:
                hint_text: 'Date'
                width: 100

            MDTextField:
                hint_text: 'Weight'
                width: 80

            MDTextField:
                hint_text: 'Weight'
                width: 80
```

**Edit**:
New code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from plyer import filechooser

Window.size = (300, 530)

KV = """
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        id: progress_toolbar
        title: 'Progress'

    ScrollView:
        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 2
            adaptive_height: True
            spacing: (10, 15)
            padding: [25, 25]

            MDLabel:
                halign: 'center'
                text: 'Before'

            MDLabel:
                halign: 'center'
                text: 'Now'

            MDCard:
                ripple_behavior: True
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                size: 120, 220
                elevation: 15
                radius: 8
                MDIconButton:
                    icon: "camera-outline"
                    user_font_size: "24sp"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    on_release: app.file_chooser1()
                Image:
                    id: img1
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                    # size_hint_y: .5

            MDCard:
                ripple_behavior: True
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                size: 120, 220
                elevation: 15
                radius: 8
                MDIconButton:
                    icon: "camera-outline"
                    user_font_size: "24sp"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    on_release: app.file_chooser2()
                Image:
                    id: img2
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                    # size_hint_y: .5


            MDTextField:
                hint_text: 'Date'
                width: 100

            MDTextField:
                hint_text: 'Date'
                width: 100

"""


class Example(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def file_chooser1(self):
        filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.selected1)

    def file_chooser2(self):
        filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.selected2)

    def selected1(self, selection1):
        self.root.ids.img1.source = selection1[0]

    def selected2(self, selection2):
        self.root.ids.img2.source = selection2[0]


Example().run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `FileManager` widget, there is actually a better alternative which is from the [plyer module](https://github.com/kivy/plyer), specifically the  `filechooser` API. What it does is to open up the default file manager app of your device to either choose folder, file or save file. Here is an example:

```
def file_manager_open(self):
    from plyer import filechooser
    path = filechooser.open_file()[0] 
    # this method returns a list with the first index
    # being the path of the file selected
    toast(path)
```

More information regarding the APIs of this library [here](https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest).

One tip I can give you is that because this file chooser is very weak on the Windows platform, I would recommend using `tkinter`'s `filedialog` if you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot @weebify, That actually solves the prpblem. But after I select an image, the image doesn't appear on the screen.. please what I am doing wrong

Comment: I believe it's because the `select_path` method of yours isn't called after choosing your desired image, thus not showing the image. I've edited my answer so that it should show up, check it out

Comment: Thanks @Weebify, but this wasn't actually displays the image, although it displays the path, but my goal is to display an image on the 'MDCard'. I really appreciate your help so, Thanks a lot..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I was able to find a video that about plyer, and I changed a lot of things in code.  I've added the new code in my previous post. The image now displays, but I now two new issues, **1.** The orientation of the image changes when it is inputed, I would like the orientation to remain the same when it is inputed. **2.** I'd love to make the inputed image file be available, when it is opened again, so I need the inputed image file to be saved.  Please how do I make these things happen. Thanks a lot for help, I really appreciate.

Comment: I don't really know what to do to make your first request work out, but the second one: Just make a save folder somewhere, for example your home directory (you can get the path by using `plyer.storagepath.get_home_dir()`), and then save your input image there. After that just make a check if there is any image file(can be named with your preference in case someone messes with the folder) and if `True` then when opening the image again, it's available. Might not be the most optimal way, but at least it's the most simple way